# How to make a sound loop as long as a button is held in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, audio, loops

So, how would I make a sound file play and loop only while a certain button is held in (iOS) ? I would also need it to stop when the button was let go? I have tried searching google and have only found forums with people asking but no real answers on how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a buttons control events touchdown, touchupinside and touchupoutside:

```
UIButton *theButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40.0, 40.0, 200.0, 30.0)];
[theButton setTitle:@"button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[theButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(startMusic) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopMusic) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[theButton addTarget:self action:@selector(stopMusic) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

edit:
realized your question may have been more about playing sound files?!

there's different frameworks, you could use AVAudioPlayer:

import framework and define a player

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
AVAudioPlayer *newPlayer;
```

create your ibactions for buttons in the main file:

```
-(IBAction)startMusic{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"mySoundFile"
                                                          ofType: @"wav"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
    newPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: fileURL error: nil];
    newPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; // Loop indefinately
    [newPlayer play];
}
```

and

```
-(IBAction)stopMusic{
    if(newPlayer isPlaying){
        [newPlayer stop];
    }
    [newPlayer release];
}
```

Comment: how would I connect all this in Interface Builder?

Comment: your ibactions have to be code. the button, however, could be done in IB. in the connections inspector you have the corresponding controlevents, connect these to the ibactions you implemented in the uiviewcontroller (declare them in the header file), which will most likely be the "file's owner"

Comment: it worked PERFECTLY! Thank you so much! I just connected startMusic to "touch down" and stopMusic to "touch up inside". Thanks again!